# Blogspot Redirect

Tags: javascript, blogger

Is this possible to always redirect

from

```
www.name.blogspot.com/title
```

to

```
www.name.blogspot.com/p/title.html
```

For example, when someone type ***[www.name.blogspot.com/title](http://www.name.blogspot.com/title)***

so it is automatically redirect to ***[www.name.blogspot.com/p/title.html](http://www.name.blogspot.com/p/title.html)***

maybe need some javascript that always auto-generate to convert incoming url to the correct url.

usually, I used this script below, but it still manually  method, so edited one by one if there is many links.

```
<script>
if(window.location.href == &#39;https://www.name.blosgpot.com/title&#39;)
{
window.location=&quot;https://www.name.blosgpot.com/p/title.html&quot;;
}
</script>
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0):

Idealy you want to do this in the server, for example, if you are using Nginx, you can rewrite incomming requests with a given pattern URL to another path:

```
server{
...
    location /title {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/p/$1 redirect;
    }
...
}
```

But if you need to do it on the client, you can use a similar logic, matching patterns and "rewriting" the URL, something like this:

```js
const myPattern = /https:\/\/name.blosgpot.com(.*)/
const path = window.location.href.match(myPattern)[1]
if (path) {
  window.location.href = "https://www.name.blosgpot.com/p" + path
}
```